# Apply DI with Unity in Custom Attribute

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi i am new to DI with unity. I am developing a custom Attribute. In that attribute I want to inject a dependency with help of Unity. But when use of that attribute in a class it shows exception. The code is:

```
public interface ITest
    {
    }
    public class AAttrib : Attribute
    {
        ITest _test;
        public AAttrib(ITest test)
        {
            _test = test;
        }
    }

    public class Test : ITest
    {
    }

    [AAttrib]
    public class Example
    {
        // to do
    }
```

the exception is:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'test' of 'AAttrib.AAttrib(ITest)

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ITest, Test>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

the Unity resolver class is:

```
public class UnityResolver: IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IUnityContainer _container;
        public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if(container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

            this._container = container;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _container.Dispose();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException r)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }

        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = _container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new UnityResolver(child);
        }
    }
```

Comment: consider Property Injection rather than Constructor injection of a dependencies.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Instead of initializing `_test` via constructor, declare property  `[Dependency]ITest _test {get;set}` and Unity will inject that property. *Note `Dependency` Attribute over property*

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Dependency Injection on Attributes, cause Attributes are Metainformation that extend the meta information of classes. And these meta information are generated during compile time

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed not possible to use DI in attributes. There is however a nice clean workaround by using a decorator.

See this blog: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/

I tried this and I've been using it for quite some time now. You will be able to do exactly what you need with this.

(Blog has .net framework & .net core solutions)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for late entry.
Not sure if unity can let you do that. But PostSharp has a way of achieving this. I've never tried this as PostSharp wasn't an approved DI framework in my project. But I liked the solution.

[Auto data contract](https://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.AutoDataContract/)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but gives a different perspective to the solution that you are thinking.

You should avoid attributes. Attributes are good starting point but get in the way of application extension. 
Attributes are hardcoding and is violation of at least two SOLID principles, Single Responsibility and Open/Closed principles. It should rather be done using Fluent APIs

I would rather replace AAttrib with a Fluent API.

## Attribute Example

```
public class Person {
    [StringLength(100)]
    [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

## FluentValidation Example:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull().WithMessage("Can't be null");
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).Length(1, 100).WithMessage("Too short or long");
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).Matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)$").WithMessage("Invalid First Name"));
    }
}
```

This will essentially do the same thing that attribute is doing. With the right DI wiring in place. This can introduce great flexibility. Read other articles on wiring attributes with members.